# Vigenere cipher exercise in Haskell

Tags: beginner, algorithm, haskell, vigenere-cipher

This is my implementation using the dreadful `!!`:

```
import Data.Char (chr, ord, toUpper)


-- A bit of self documentation help
type Key = String
type Msg = String


key :: Key
key = "TSTING"
msg :: Msg
msg = "I'm not even mad... This is impressive!"


-- | Checks if character is valid for encoding
isValid :: Char -> Bool
isValid c = let cUp = toUpper c :: Char
             in 'A' <= cUp && cUp <= 'Z'


-- | Given 'key' & 'msg' generate a list of [Maybe Int] indices
-- to map 'msg' from 'key', skipping invalid characters
toIdx :: Key -> Msg -> [Maybe Int]
toIdx k m = map (flip mod keyN <$>) $ toIdx_ 0 m
  where keyN = length k :: Int
        toIdx_ :: Int -> Msg -> [Maybe Int]
        toIdx_ _ "" = []
        toIdx_ acc (c:cs)
          | isValid c = Just acc : toIdx_ (acc + 1) cs
          | otherwise = Nothing : toIdx_ acc cs


-- | Given 'key' & 'msg' generate a list of numbers representing
-- the amount to shift 'msg' characters based on 'key'
toShifts :: Key -> Msg -> [Int]
toShifts k m = map toKey (toIdx k m)
  where kUp = map toUpper k :: Key
        toKey :: Maybe Int -> Int
        toKey Nothing  = 0
        toKey (Just x) = ord (kUp!!x) - ord 'A'


-- | Given 'by' & 'c', shift the Char 'c' by amount 'by'. 'by' can be both
-- positive & negative as well as 0.
shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift by c
  | isValid c && c >= 'a' = shift_ $ ord 'a'
  | isValid c && c >= 'A' = shift_ $ ord 'A'
  | otherwise = c
  where cONorm    = ord (toUpper c) - ord 'A' :: Int
        azN       = ord 'Z' - ord 'A' :: Int
        shift_ :: Int -> Char
        shift_ aO = chr $ aO + mod (by + cONorm) azN


-- Encode & decode a message using the given key.
vigenere, unVigenere :: Key -> Msg -> Msg
vigenere   k m = zipWith shift (toShifts k m) m
unVigenere k m = zipWith shift (map negate $ toShifts k m) m
```

I found that the most "annoying" thing when coming from background such as `Python` is to be able to keep track of things, for example when figuring out how to convert valid characters into usable positions to be then mapped with the `key`. That thing took me half a day to figure out!

How would you do it? Or is there some "standard" way of working with these sort of things? I'm referring particularly to `toIdx` & `toIdx_`, had to use `toIdx_` to accumulate the indices with `acc` in this list of `Maybe Int` in order to correctly map valid `Char`s with `key`.

Of course, I wouldn't have it any other way but have an algorithm which takes any `String` input and creates an encoded `String` with preserved upper/lower-case and non-valid (out of ASCII alphabet) `Char`s.

Comment: Welcome to SE Code Review. 1st note: None of the SE sites is designed as a _forum_. _"I'm not sure about the rules here"_  You can always make yourself familiar with the rules and policies reading the material in the [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ of course, but we both know people are lazy and it's easier to wait for someone to shout at you on your first try :P

Comment: Who was shouting? You also miss the {informed} badge. Well, as you've been mentioning _the rules_, I was just tempted to tell you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you're talking it too literally :). I wasn't referring to you when saying about shouting

Comment: the -1 is for _I'm not sure about the rules here_

Comment: @t3chb0t Aww, that's harsh ;-)

Comment: As a matter of fact for someone who didn't read the rules your question is fine. If you only haven't told us this, no one would have noticed :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t that's just me being honest, I accept my punishment! :)

Comment: @razvanc Well, one important thing you should notice here (one of the reason it's different from a _forum_): Down- or Upvotes refer to the posts quality, not as punishment or reward for the OP. You can always edit your post in course of improvement. Removing that statement would improve your post, because from the topic point of view it is just unnecessary noise, that distracts future readers.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but for some inspiration, have a look at [my previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160325/21002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rather close. The issue lies within `zipWith`. `zipWith` will *always*  consume the first elements of both lists. That's why you need `(toShifts k m)` to begin with.

However, what if we get rid of `zipWith` for a moment and use pattern matching in `vigenere`?

```
vigenere' :: Key -> Msg -> Msg
vigenere' ks     (' ':ms) = ' '        : vigenere ks ms
vigenere' (k:ks) (m  :ms) = shiftC k m : vigenere ks ms
vigenere' _      []       = []
```

where `shiftC :: Char -> Char -> Char` is an appropriate function (left as an exercise). Actually, that's it. That's all that is necessary for `vigenere`, apart from `shiftC`. Well, I'm lying: the key will run out at some point. That's why you use `cycle :: [a] -> [a]`:

```
vigenere :: Key -> Msg -> Msg
vigenere ks ms = vigenere' (cycle ks) ms
```

`cycle` turns a regular list in an infinite one, e.g. `cycle [1,2,3] == [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,…]` (exercise: try to implement cycle). Therefore, it turns your key into an infinite one.

You can implement `unVigenere'` the same way, only that you need `unShiftC :: Char -> Char -> Char`. A pair of functions, namely `toInt :: Char -> Int` and `fromInt :: Int -> Char` will come in handy for that (left as an exercise).

Heck, we can even implement both functions the same way and use `isValid` instead of pattern matching for unsupported characters:

```
cryptZip' :: (Char -> Char -> Char) -> Key -> Msg -> Msg
cryptZip' _ _      []       = []
cryptZip' f (k:ks) (m  :ms) =
  | isValid m = f k m : cryptZip' f ks     ms
  | otherwise = m     : cryptZip' f (k:ks) ms

-- | Combines the key and the message with the given function.
-- Invalid characters are left as-is. The function shall return
-- only valid characters.
cryptZip :: (Char -> Char -> Char) -> Key -> Msg -> Msg
cryptZip f ks ms = cryptZip' f (cycle ks) ms
```

Now, `vigenere` and `unVigenere` are extremely simple:

```
vigenere   = cryptZip shiftC
unVigenere = cryptZip unShiftC
```

And we're done. By the way, you can use `(Char -> Char -> Maybe Char)` to get rid of `isValid`. But that, again, is left as an exercise.

## Further remarks

The type annotations in your `where` bindings are not necessary. I would get rid of them, since they may get out of sync with your top-level function (but you will at least get a type-error).

`cryptZip` can be written as `(a -> a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, if you're up for a challenge.

Your overall complexity stemmed from `zipWith`. It's a great function, but only if it's used for the right job. Not everything is a nail, just because you have a hammer at hand. 
Instead of trying to get everything else in place to use a specific function, ask yourself what you want to do, and whether there's an easy way. Unfortunately, there is no `cryptZip`-like function in the standard library (unless you count stateful accumulators such as `mapAccumL`).

Comment: I was just about to answer on your other comment :) cause I just went through [your other](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160325/21002) explanation. Only thing I don't like about it really is that pattern matching on `' '`. What if we use `TAB` or some other symbol? We of course don't want to shift those, that's why I have the `zipWith` and all that funky `!!` stuff - which yes, I don't like, but I do like to try reimplementing it with @Gurkenglas' solution to `toIdx_` and then I'll just have to experiment some more :). Thanks!

Comment: @razvanc that's why `cryptZip'` uses `isValid`, and the exercise variant uses `Char -> Char -> Maybe Char`. And yeah, the non-pattern-matching variant is hidden in the exercises in the other question.

Comment: I'll have to go over your solution again and process it slower :) to fully get the ins-&-outs of it. Thanks for your time :).

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't call Gurkenglas' second solution best practice. It's clever, but rather obfuscated.

Comment: Well I'm not entitled to say it since I'm such a n00b at Haskell but I do get that feeling, yes :)

Comment: In that case, feel free to add [tag:beginner] to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57626/discussion-between-razvanc-and-zeta).

Comment: Nice explanation! I got some time to go over this again. You've got a bug :) `cryptZip' f (k:ks) ms` should switch places with `cryptZip' f ks     ms`. Actually my initial complexity stemmed from the fact that I didn't know (still don't know a bunch of) about `cycle` & other useful functions & the fact that I wanted to use `shift` generically so I can `unShift` just by providing the 'inverse'. With `shift :: Int -> Char -> Maybe Char` you could just negate the first parameter for `unShift`. But I do like generics and your answer is definitely the one :). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of `!!` here, you can use it earlier and earlier until you never even generate an `Int`.

```
-- | Given 'key' & 'msg' generate a list of [Maybe Int] indices
-- to map 'msg' from 'key', skipping invalid characters
toIdx :: Key -> Msg -> [Maybe Char]
toIdx k m = toIdx_ (cycle $ map toUpper k) m
  where toIdx_ :: Key -> Msg -> [Maybe Char]
        toIdx_ _ "" = []
        toIdx_ key@(k:ey) (c:cs)
          | isValid c = Just k : toIdx_ ey cs
          | otherwise = Nothing : toIdx_ key cs


-- | Given 'key' & 'msg' generate a list of numbers representing
-- the amount to shift 'msg' characters based on 'key'
toShifts :: Key -> Msg -> [Int]
toShifts k m = map toKey (toIdx k m)
  where toKey :: Maybe Char -> Int
        toKey Nothing  = 0
        toKey (Just x) = ord x - ord 'A'
```

Of course, there is hardly a need to separate all these steps.

```
base :: Char -> Maybe Char
base c
  | 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' = Just 'a'
  | 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' = Just 'A'
  | otherwise = Nothing

vigenere, unVigenere :: String -> String -> String
[vigenere, unVigenere] = (`map` [(+), (-)]) $ \direction k ->
  (.) snd $ (`mapAccumL` cycle k) $ \key@(k:ey) c -> case base c of
    Nothing -> (key, c)
    Just a -> (,) ey $ chr $ ord a +
      mod ((ord c - ord a) `direction` (ord (toUpper k) - ord 'A')) (ord 'Z' - ord 'A')
```

Comment: I really like the solution you have for `toIdx_` on the first code block. That's clever :). There's a few problems with it tho', signature should be `... -> [Maybe Char]` and it should be called with `toIdx_ (cycle $ map toUpper k) m` if I'm not mistaking. At the time I wrote the code I didn't know about `cycle` nor I do about `mapAccumL` and your second solution is way to terse for me, quite literally not understandable :D. Coming from Python I kind of have it ingrained in my style that explicit is better than implicit. Thanks for your time!